# How to Show Side Menu instead of Back Button on particular page (ionic2)?

Tags: angular, ionic2

Hi How to show Side Menu instead of Backbutton in ionic2  ...

Here is my Code I want to make side menu present in this view ...

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Myrepeat</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

Testing Page

</ion-content>
```

My myrepeat.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'myrepeat.html'
})
export class Myrepeat {


 constructor (private http: Http) {}



}
```

Comment: Where's your code of angular 2 component?

Comment: Hi I have Added .ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the back button you have to use `setRoot`

please take a look at this [navControll](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/) you have to use something like this `this.navCtrl.setRoot('PageName',{});`

Comment: Not working for me. I'm already using setRoot yet it still shows the back button sometimes when it should be showing the menu button. Extremely frustrating